# python turtle event listener global variable isn't working

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have a project, and I want the global variable `size` to change whenever you press the up arrow. This is part of my code:

```
size = 10

def increase():
    global size
    size += 1
    print("hi")

screen.onkeypress(increase, "Up")
```

but when I run the program and press the up arrow, then check `size`, it is still 10.

Any idea why?

Any help is appreciated. =D

Comment: Are you already using the `listen()` method on the `Screen` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include **listen()** method to record your actions.

```
size = 10

def increase():
    global size
    size += 1
    print("hi")

screen.onkey(increase, "Up")
screen.listen()
```